# Detecting a faulty component when resistance to ground != 0

Tags: voltage, current, resistance

I have a board with a 3.3V line whose resistance to ground = 80 Ohms. This voltage goes to many components so while taking each component off is an option, it is rather tedious. I also have BGA components which I cannot remove.

I have tried supplying this voltage from an external power supply, but due to the resistance not being 0, that doesn't help me the culprit at all, all I see is that when measuring the voltage on a multimeter or scope I get a result of about 2.9V.

I can't provide any schematics, I can only tell you the problem in general.

Anyone got any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: are you sure that 80 ohms is a fault? How are you measuring this? Non-resistive components will give you nonsense readings if you are measuring with a classic multimeter in ohm mode.

Comment: No... It would be guesswork without more info. Telling us the resistance to ground isn't really telling us any information about a fault. What is it supposed to be? Why can you not provide any of the schematic?

Comment: What makes you assume that faulty components always create a short to ground? Many components fail open or fail with a certain resistance which is not zero. Trying to identify the fault like you're trying to do will get you nowhere. You will have to investigate what works as expected and what does not.

Comment: Also you need to check that your PSU is capable of supplying the required current at 3.3 V.

Comment: @JorenVaes 80 ohms is a fault because other boards of the same type have a larger resistance.

Comment: @MCG I can't provide schematics because it's not my own and I am not allowed to share it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie See my answer to Joren. I know the 3.3V is problematic because I accidentally shorted it to ground while testing, which caused the total current consumption to be 200mA larger than usual. This, basically, is the problem. It causes BGA components in my board to overheat but not to the point where it becomes unusable. Still, this isn't normal.

Comment: @Transistor it is. It can provide 5A if voltage is 15V or less.

Comment: @Eran you will have to then go component by component to figure it out. With the information we have, it would be little more than guesswork. Start with that 3.3V regulator and go from there

Comment: @MCG I understand this is like guesswork, but I really can't provide schematics (it's also 30+ pages long, trust me, you don't want to go there). I was hoping there is a much better technique than go component by component. Also, I know for a fact it's not the regulator.

Comment: Then you can try the split technique. Cut the circuit in half, see which half the fault is and then split that bit in half, and so on and so forth. That's another technique you can use. Unfortunately, that's the best we can do. There is too little information to make a proper guess, so it's likely you won't get an answer

Comment: Do you have a working board to compare temperatures of components? Has this board ever worked? Has this design ever worked? Does the current increase linearly with voltage, or have a diode curve?

Comment: @W5VO This design is proven to be working and I have some boards that can be used as references. This is how I know that 80Ohms between 3.3V to ground is not normal. About you other question, I'm sorry but I don't know. Do you mean the main voltage or the 3.3V?

Comment: I mean the 3.3V rail - if you ramp the voltage from say 0 to 3.3V (not sure if you can if you have a few different power rails), does the power increase linearly (resistive short), increase rapidly after one diode drop, or maybe two diode drops (reversed component)?

Comment: @W5VO I don't know, I've never tried doing something like that. I do have lots of different power rails and since the 3.3V goes to BGA components like CPU and FPGA I'm not sure if I should even try doing something like that. Do you think trying something like that would be dangerous for the circuit?

Comment: If you can't really power up the 3.3V rail in isolation, (e.g. a processor needs a 1.2V Vcore) then it probably won't tell you too much anyways and *may* be dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

This seems overkill but I manager to find such faulty components using a thermal camera. This is really a good option to find where the power is dissipated.
Of course, you need a thermal camera, but estimating the temperature with a finger may also help, especially if you have another board working (of course, not if there is 110/230V on the board!).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do have a thermal camera but it doesn't help, probably due to the voltage not being pulled to ground. Nothing overheats, so touching with my finger or cleaning the board with alcohol doesn't help (I've tried).